# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_self referenced in function

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

I'm trying to generate a pthread lib for wp8, but the lib file seems not work. I take the function `thread_self()` as an example to explain it.

First, I use the command to check the .lib: `dumpbin /symbols pthread_lib.lib`

When I grep the output with 'pthread_self', the output contains information like this:

```
01D 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
023 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
01A 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
011 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
011 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
011 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
011 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
011 00000000 SECT4  notype ()    External     | _pthread_self
012 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
012 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
018 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
012 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
014 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
011 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
024 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
40D 00000000 SECTAE notype ()    External     | _pthread_self
059 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
08B 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
054 00000000 SECT10 notype ()    External     | _pthread_self
012 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
036 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__pthread_self
```

It means that `pthread_self` is included in the lib, doesn't it?

---

Second, I created a console application project, change settings like this:

1. set "c/c++ -> additional include directories" to `.\headers;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

   (headers dir is where pthread.h is placed in)
2. set "linker -> additional library directories" to  `.\libs;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)`

   （libs dir is where pthread_lib.lib is placed in)
3. append "linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies" with pthread_lib.lib;

---

And the ConsoleApplication1.cpp is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "pthread.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    pthread_self();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Then when I ran it, got the error:

> `Error    1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_self referenced in function _wmain ...\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj`

How to check and resolve it?

Comment: 'UNDEF' doesn't look like it is defined in this library.  Is there another library where it is defined that you need to link against?

Comment: Thanks @GrahamGriffiths I grep the output with 'pthread_self' again and pasted the list here. Some of them are not 'UNDEF'. Sorry I'm not clear about the meanings of them.